# ASP.NET Update Progress When Using HttpContext

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an ASP.NET page that collects some criteria from the user with ASP.NET controls and then based on the values of the controls, uses HttpContext.Current.Response to generate output to a CSV from the web page.

The issue I'm having is that it may take a minute or so for my response to be generated. Thus, I would like to implement a progress bar of some kind from the time my user submits the request until the time the CSV is delivered. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get my hidden div to display and hide on demand with EnablePartialRendering set to false in ScriptManager (this is necessary for populating other controls on the page).

Is there any way to implement a progress bar (either server or client-side) to monitor the status of HttpContext output?

Answer (score 0):

The [`UpdateProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx) class isn't a progress bar. It's purpose it to provide feedback that a partial postback is happening, not to communicate to the browser the actual progress of that partial postback

My favorite JavaScriptish(supports all major plugins as well) library to do what you are asking is [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/):

Examples can be seen [here](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php).

Answer (score 0):

No.  At least not the way you are thinking.  If you're going to send a file back to the user, then you cannot issue any HTML to the user beforehand.  You have to send the file as a stand-alone response.

What you CAN do is what many other sites do, which is to perform the process in the background, and redirect the user to a page that has an animation to indicate something is happening.  You use Javascript to cause the page to refresh every few seconds until the background process is done, then return the file.

This complicates the process, and requires a lot more work.  The question you have to ask is, is this progress really worth it?

EDIT:

Didn't notice you were using Ajax, in which case you can simply have an animation on the page that is normally hidden, then when you perform the process you unhide the animation and let it spin.  This can't show actual progress, but it does show that somethign is happening.  When the process is done, you hide the animation again, then send the file.

If you are going to use javascript to do the download, you have some other options... but none of this relates to the progress of the preperation to download.

Comment: But if the animation is client-based, how will I know when my server-based HttpContext is done responding so I can remove the animation?

Comment: @kittyhawk - if you're doing ajax, then you have to be starting the download through some ajax method.  When that method returns, you can execute a callback to hide the animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ajax this is the best way to do

```
$('#loadinganimation')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
});
```